How do I build a Bezier curve for this drawing?
I am designing a rocket engine and I needed to draw the contour of its nozzle, where the Bezier curve is used, but I do not quite understand how to draw it. Can you suggest formulas or methods of its construction, or maybe software for this.

Start with point $A$. Draw a circle around it with the radius $r_{ckp}$.
Draw point $C$.
Draw a Bezier curve that starts at $C$ with angle $\theta_a$, and ends
with a tangent to the circle you drew at step 1, at an angle
$\theta_m$.
Draw another circle for the curve on the left side of the throat.



Is my answer working for you, or not?

Let $T$ be the tangency point between the circle with center $A$ and the Bézier curve: the angle between line $AT$ and the vertical is then $\theta_m$.
You can, for instance, set up a coordinate system and find the coordinates of the tangency point $T$, of point $C$ and of point $f$ (the intersection between the tangent lines), using the information given in the figure.
The parametric equation of the Bézier curve is then:
$$
P(t)=(1-t)^{2} T + 2t(1-t) f+t^{2}C,\quad 0\leq t\leq 1.
$$
If you don't want to use coordinates, you can follow the construction suggested in your figure: divide segments $Tf$ and $fC$ into the same number $n$ of equal parts ($n=6$ in the figure) and number the endpoints of those parts from $1$ to $n-1$. Join then the points with same numbers with $n-1$ lines: the resulting polyline will give an approximation of the Bézier curve.
